# Not able to get the windowHandle of a WebDriver (created using ThreadLocal) on SauceLabs

Tags: selenium, saucelabs

I have created a webDriver using the following code:

https://github.com/saucelabs-sample-test-frameworks/Java-TestNG-Selenium/blob/master/src/test/java/com/yourcompany/Tests/TestBase.java

So basically I am creating a WebDriver as

```
protected ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
```

Now when I am trying to get the windowHandle, it seems I am getting the value of thread.

```
String parentHandle = driver.get().getWindowHandle();
```

I get response as "6"

The code works fine when I run it locally and not in sauce labs , on running locally I get the handle value as something like "213456789345"

Comment: I debug some more, and it seems the code works for Chrome but not for Firefox. This is the configuration:                                               
       "platform": "OS X 10.12",
       "browserName": "firefox",
       "version": "59",
       "unhandledPromptBehavior": "accept",
        "seleniumVersion": "3.10.0"